# JTable multiple selection without the CTRL

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm trying to change the Selection behaviour of a JTable to be able to add and remove rows to the selection without using the CTRL modifier. The method:

```
public void changeSelection(int rowIndex,
                        int columnIndex,
                        boolean toggle,
                        boolean extend)
```

seems to be exactly what I'm looking for, in particular the case:

```
toggle: true, extend: false. If the specified cell is selected, deselect it. If it is not selected, select it.
```

is what I mean to do. The problem is I can't make it work. Maybe I'm missing some info about internal JTable workings, but here's my code:

```
initComponents();

    mainTable.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
    mainTable.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);

    mainTable.setSelectionModel(new DefaultListSelectionModel() {
        @Override
        public void addSelectionInterval(int index0, int index1) {
            if (index0 == index1) {
                for (int i = 0; i < mainTable.getColumnModel().getColumnCount(); i++) {
                    mainTable.changeSelection(index0, i, true, false);
                }
            }
        }

    });
```

this seems to be doing nothing. Can anybody tell me what is the problem please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom `ListSelectionModel`.

Simple example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ToggleListSelectionModel extends DefaultListSelectionModel
{
    @Override
    public void setSelectionInterval(int index0, int index1)
    {
        //  Select multiple lines

        if (index0 != index1)
        {
            super.addSelectionInterval(index0, index1);
            return;
        }

        //  Toggle selection of a single line

        if  (super.isSelectedIndex(index0))
        {
            super.removeSelectionInterval(index0, index0);
        }
        else
        {
            super.addSelectionInterval(index0, index0);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        String[] numbers = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten" };
        final JList<String> list = new JList<String>( numbers );
        list.setVisibleRowCount( numbers.length );
        list.setSelectionModel(new ToggleListSelectionModel());
//      list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);

        JButton clear = new JButton("Clear");
        clear.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                list.clearSelection();
            }
        });

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(list), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(clear, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The example is for a JList, but a JTable also uses a ListSelectionModel.

Comment: This still works (Java 8) and also with a `JTable`.